# Codeigniter subquery join

Tags: database, codeigniter, activerecord

How do i write in codeigniter in active record the following query?

select tbl_list.id, tbl_list_items.name
from tbl_list
join tbl_list_items
on tbl_list_items.id=(select tbl_list_items.id from tbl_list_items where list_id=tbl_list.id order by tbl_list_items.item_no asc LIMIT 1)

Update:

This is what i come out with but it does not do the job.

```
$this->db->select($this->table_list.'.*');
$this->db->from($this->table_list);
$sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('join','',$this->table_list_items.'.id');
$sub->select('id')->from($this->table_list_items)->where('list_id','tbl_list.id')->order_by($this->table_list_items.'item_no','asc')->limit('1');
$this->subquery->end_subquery('list_items');
```

Appreciate any helps. Thanks.

Comment: Finally changed the statement to

select tbl_list.id, tbl_list_items.name from tbl_list
join tbl_list_items
on tbl_list_items.id=(select tbl_list_items.id from tbl_list_items where listing_id=tbl_list.id order by item_no asc LIMIT 1);

Active record seems more happy with this.

Comment: You can always use Active Record with a straight SQL statement. But then you're not leveraging the breaking down of the statement into interchangeable components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Review the Active Record methods available to you in CodeIgniter.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select)

[Then review a CI library to extend it to handle subqueries available on CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Subqueries)

[There is a walk-through about how CI is doing this under-the-hood](http://heybigname.com/2009/09/18/using-code-igniters-active-record-class-to-create-subqueries/)

**[Found a github codebase for implementing subqueries in CodeIgniter 1.7 and 2.x (see link)](https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries)**

**EDIT:**

Revised Code is below to assist. You can also check out the 4th link's examples.

To replicate what you'er trying to do, the code would be similar to (this is un-tested... but hopefully starts you on the right path):

```
$this->db->select('tbl_list.id, tbl_list.names');
$this->db->from('tbl_list');
$sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('join', 'left', 'tli.id = tbl_list.id');
$sub->select('tbl_list_items.id')->from('tbl_list_items')->where('tbl_list_items.list_id=tbl_list.id ');
$sub->db->order_by('ASC');
$sub->db->limit(1);
$this->subquery->end_subquery('tli');
```

The key is this statement: **$this->subquery->end_subquery('tli');**
What happens there, is that it treats the result of the subquery as **AS tli** so that you can reference it in **tli.id**.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I don't get the third line, the tbl_list_items.id is not equal to tbl_list.id but to the select. I read up docs but it does not show the way to subquery right from the join on. Any advise.

Comment: Try this for the third line: $sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('join', tbl_list_items.id = list_ids'); For the rest of the query, create a SELECT statement that uses '...AS 'list_ids'. I'll write it out later today.

Comment: Updated with a link to subquery library for AR in CI and new codebase with explanation.